# CLEditor/TinyMCE rendering incorectly

Tags: java, spring, oracle, tinymce, cleditor

I am attempting to incorporate [CLEditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/CLEditor) into one of my applications. But somewhere this is a disconnect causing some rendering problems.

Front end uses jQuery/HTML/CSS backend is using Java/Oracle/Spring/Struts 2 and I am not quite sure where the problem is surfacing.  I think it is CLEditor getting confused somehow.

My code looks like the following.

```
<textarea id="editor" name="contractTemplate.contractBody" value="${contractTemplate.contractBody}"></textarea>
```

And further down the page I have CLEditor set ups as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {

    $('#editor').cleditor({
      width: 'auto',
      height: 300,
      controls: "font bold italic | " +
              "bullets numbering | " +
              "alignleft center alignright justify | " +
              "outdent indent | " +
              "undo redo " +
              "rule | cut copy paste pastetext | print source",
      fonts: // font names in the font popup
              "Arial,Arial Black,Courier New,Narrow,Garamond," +
              "Georgia,Sans Serif,Serif,Tahoma,Trebuchet MS,Verdana",
      bodyStyle: "margin:4px; font: 10pt Arial, Verdana; cursor:text",
      docType: '<!DOCTYPE html>'
    });


  });
</script>
```

When I first load up the page that the `textarea` lives on it displays nicely.  I am able to format things as I wish using left align, right align, center.  I am able to create proper looking `ul` and `ol` (most of the functions I need).  I am also able to view the code using the `Show Source` provided.  I submit to my `Action` and it saves the formatted text I sent in a `CLOB` as expected.  However when I revisit the page to edit (one of my use cases) previously formatted text is damaged...  Typically if I have right aligned some text it strips tags from it forcing a left align and a `">` is added to the end of the `textarea`.  You can imagine the confusion that gets introduced from there.  If you don't catch the `">` and save it removes all text with only the `">` surviving and a subsequent save will leave you with `"&gt;` saved to the database.

Where might this problem be coming from?  I have been unable to find anyone having a similar problem searching around thus far.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit:**

Perhaps the problem has nothing to do with CLEditor...   I just threw [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) with a quick install:

```
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
        tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
</script>
```

And I get the same behavior...

**Edit:**

Further investigation shows that somewhere along the line things are not being escaped properly.

This is from the `Inspect Element` feature:

```
<textarea aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" id="editor" name="contractTemplate.contractBody" value="<p style=" text-align:="" right;"="">Right Align&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p style="text-align: center;"&gt;Center&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p style="text-align: left;"&gt;Left Align&lt;/p&gt;"&gt;</textarea>
```

As you can see the  the `value="<p style"` ends up closing the quote and does not escape things properly. the further down the page things change from `< and >` to `&gt; and &lt;`  I see the problem but am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone hopefully will benefit from my lack of paying attention...  There is nothing wrong with either of the editors.  The problem described above was a matter of me not paying attention to what I was doing.  Rather than removing the question I will leave it so that hopefully someone will search and see what I did wrong to fix their problem...

When using a `textarea` do not use `<textarea value="some value"></textarea>`  Use `<textarea>some value</textarea>`